# How to persist reordering items when using a single entity in CoreData?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, core-data

The user can reorder items in a UITableView, the data is from a single entity. I want to persist the order of which the user has defined (by moving the items) back into CoreData so that when I fetch the records back the order will be what the user defined. I know you could simply do this by having an integer attribute in the model, but that would be inefficient if I had a lot of records as I would have to update every other record. Is there an elegant way I could achieve this, without having to use the approach I mentioned? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these items are related to some other item, you could use an ordered to-many relationship from that other item. That's the only option provided by Core Data.

For what it's worth, if you add a sort index, you *don't* need to update "every" other record when the user changes the order. You only need to update those between the start and end position of the change. For example if the user moves something from index 2 to index 12, the item at index 1 is still at index 1, and the items at index 13 through 80 billion also have the same index.